# PKI: why is leaked CA certificate a threat?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

According to the SSL/TLS threat model from ssllabs:

https://www.ssllabs.com/downloads/SSL_Threat_Model.png

Why is "Leaked CA Certificates" a threat? (In the "Trust (PKI)" branch)
Isn't the purpose of a certificate to be publically available?

I understand, why "Rogue CA Certificates" is a threat, but why is "Leaked CA Certificates" a threat?

Comment: I guess they include the private keys in their understanding of "certificate". Seems unreasonable but imaginable to me.

Comment: ok this could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As marstato seems to have already said, by 'Leaked CA certificate', they seem to be implying the private key for the signing certificate as well. Which would enable anyone to sign their own certificates and hence the issue.